# Java - I think my boolean is defaulting to true for some reason

Tags: boolean

I'm having an issue with my hangman program. When I run it, the label holding the  int variable "lives" is supposed to update when you guess a wrong letter. But for some reason it isn't. I've placed this in my code as a test mechanism, and it isn't appearing even here.

```
    if (used[letter] = false) {
    System.out.println("test");
```

However, when I place it here.. It DOES work..

```
if (finished == false) {
    boolean found = false;
    boolean www = false;
    System.out.println("test");
        if (used[letter] = false) {
```

It almost leads me to believe that used[letter] is true by default, when it really shouldn't be. The variable is declared at the very top. Any thoughts?

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList; 


public class Hangman implements ActionListener {
JFrame frame;
JPanel stats = new JPanel();
JLabel currentWordLA = new JLabel("Current word:");
JLabel triedLettersLA = new JLabel("Tried letters:");
JLabel triesLeftLA = new JLabel("Tries remaining:");
private String[] wordList = {"computer","java","activity","alaska","appearance","article", 
   "automobile","basket","birthday","canada","central","character","chicken","chosen", 
   "cutting","daily","darkness","diagram","disappear","driving","effort","establish","exact", 
   "establishment","fifteen","football","foreign","frequently","frighten","function","gradually", 
   "hurried","identity","importance","impossible","invented","italian","journey","lincoln", 
   "london","massage","minerals","outer","paint","particles","personal","physical","progress", 
   "quarter","recognise","replace","rhythm","situation","slightly","steady","stepped", 
   "strike","successful","sudden","terrible","traffic","unusual","volume","yesterday" }; 
public String mysteryWord; 
public int lives;
private boolean finished = false;
private boolean won = false;
private Button a[];
public boolean used[] = new boolean[26];


public static void main (String[] args) {
    Hangman gui = new Hangman();
    gui.go();
    }

class myDrawPanel extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        setBackground(Color.white);
        g.setColor(Color.gray);
     g.fillRect(50, 200, 150, 20);
     g.fillRect(90,20,10,200);
     g.fillRect(90,20,60,10);
     g.setColor(Color.black);
     g.fillRect(145,20,5,25);
        g.setColor(Color.green);
            if (lives < 6 )
            g.drawOval(132,45,30,30);
            if (lives < 5 )
            g.drawLine(147,75,147,100);
        if (lives < 4 )
            g.drawLine(147,100,167,133);
        if (lives < 3 )
            g.drawLine(147,100,127,133);
        if (lives < 2 )
            g.drawLine(147,75,167,85);
        if (lives < 1 )
            g.drawLine(147,75,127,85);

        StringBuffer guessed = new StringBuffer();
            for (int cl = 0; cl < mysteryWord.length(); cl++) {
            if (used[(int)mysteryWord.charAt(cl)-'a'])
            guessed.append(mysteryWord.charAt(cl));
           else
              guessed.append("*");
           }
            currentWordLA.setText("Current word: " + guessed.toString());



         if (lives < 1) {
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillRect(70, 200, 200, 30);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawString(mysteryWord.toString(),75,230);
            Font fff = new Font("Helvetica",Font.BOLD,36);
            g.setFont(fff);

            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.drawString("You lose!",200,100);

            //finished = true;
            }

         if (won) {
            Font fff = new Font("Helvetica",Font.BOLD,36);
            g.setFont(fff);

//                Color red=new Color.red
            g.setColor(Color.red);

            g.drawString("You Win!",200,100);
            //finished = true;
            }
  }
 }

public void go() {

///////////////////////DESIGN BEGIN//////////////////////////////////////////////
    frame = new JFrame("Hangman");
    JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
    myDrawPanel noosePanel = new myDrawPanel();
    JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel scorePanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout( new GridLayout( 2, 0) );
    bottomPanel.setLayout( new GridLayout( 0, 2) );
    scorePanel.setSize(20,100);

    noosePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Your progress.")); 
    topPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Your arsenal.")); 
    scorePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Your score.")); 
frame.add(topPanel);
frame.add(bottomPanel);
    bottomPanel.add(scorePanel);
    bottomPanel.add(noosePanel);

//Just the stats panel.
    JButton restart = new JButton("Reset");

        currentWordLA.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 10));
        currentWordLA.setForeground(Color.black);
        triedLettersLA.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 10));
        triedLettersLA.setForeground(Color.black);
        triesLeftLA.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 10));
        triesLeftLA.setForeground(Color.black);
        restart.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        restart.setForeground(Color.red);

            stats.setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); 
            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints(); 
            c.gridx = 0; 
            c.gridy = 0; 
            c.insets = new Insets(20,0,0,0); 
            c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
            stats.add(currentWordLA, c); 
            c.gridx = 0; 
            c.gridy = 1; 
            c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
            stats.add(triedLettersLA, c); 
            c.gridx = 0; 
            c.gridy = 2; 
            c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
            stats.add(triesLeftLA, c); 
            c.gridx = 0; 
            c.gridy = 3; 
            c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
            stats.add(restart, c); 
            scorePanel.add(stats);
///////////////////////DESIGN END////////////////////////////////////////////// 
///////////////////////ALPHABET BEGIN//////////////////////////////////////////
    int i;
    StringBuffer buffer;
    a = new Button[26];
    topPanel.setLayout( new GridLayout( 4,0, 10, 10) );
    for (i = 0; i <26; i++) {
           buffer = new StringBuffer();
            buffer.append((char)(i+'a'));
            a[i] = new Button(buffer.toString());
            a[i].setSize(100,100);
            a[i].addActionListener( this );
          topPanel.add(a[i]);
        }
///////////////////////ALPHABET END//////////////////////////////////////////
//Just shows the entire window.                  
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
//////////////////////GAMEPLAY BEGIN////////////////////////////////////////
    lives = 6;
    triesLeftLA.setText("Tries remaining: " + lives);
    mysteryWord = wordGen();    

}

//Returns a random word from the wordList bank.
    private String wordGen() {
        return wordList[0 + (int)(Math.random() * ((63 - 0) + 1)) ]; //Make sure to set these to nonprinted chars eventually
    }

    public void consultWord(int letter) {
        if (finished == false) {
            boolean found = false;
        boolean www = false;
                if (used[letter] = false) {
                System.out.println("test");
                for (int cl = 0 ; cl < mysteryWord.length(); cl++) {
                if (mysteryWord.charAt(cl)==((char)(letter + 'a'))) {
                            found = true;
                        }
                    }
                if (found == false) {
                            lives = lives - 1;
                            triesLeftLA.setText    ("Tries remaining: " + lives);
                        }
                }

    used[letter] = true;

            for (int cl = 0; cl < mysteryWord.length(); cl++) {
            if (!used[(int)(mysteryWord.charAt(cl)) - 'a']){
                    www = true;
                }
            }
            if (www == false) {
                won = true;        
            }
            frame.repaint();
    }
    }

    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            if (e.getSource() == a[i]) { 
            consultWord(i); }
  }
}       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make that:

```
if (used[letter] == false) {
    System.out.println("test");
```

Comment: Happens to the best of us! Good luck with the rest of your project.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (used[letter] = false) {
```

You just set `used[letter]` to `false`. Try `==`

Of course, to avoid this typo you shouldn't be using `==` but rather ...

```
if (!used[letter]) {
```